# Pandas column with True if it's the first time a value appeared in another column or False

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transaction dataset with purchase dates from clients. I want to create a column saying if it's a new client or a repeated one.

```
id  date        Expected Result
1   2021-01-15  False
2   2021-01-02  True
1   2021-01-03  True
3   2021-01-04  True
4   2021-01-05  True
3   2021-01-06  False
1   2021-01-05  False
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is `duplicated`:

```
 df['new'] = ~df.sort_values(['date']).duplicated('id')

Output:

   id        date  Expected  Result    new
0   1  2021-01-15     False     NaN  False
1   2  2021-01-02      True     NaN   True
2   1  2021-01-03      True     NaN   True
3   3  2021-01-04      True     NaN   True
4   4  2021-01-05      True     NaN   True
5   3  2021-01-06     False     NaN  False
6   1  2021-01-05     False     NaN  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dataframe by id and date then use cumcount to count client occurence

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1],
        'date': ['2021-01-10', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-05']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
#Column with number of occurence for the id
df['new'] = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date']).groupby('id').cumcount()+1

id  date        new
1   2021-01-15  3
2   2021-01-02  1
1   2021-01-03  1
3   2021-01-04  1
4   2021-01-05  1
3   2021-01-06  2
1   2021-01-05  2
```

Then just replace when it's 1 for True else it's False

```
df['new'] = [True if x == 1 else False for x in df['new']]


id  date        new
1   2021-01-10  False
2   2021-01-02  True
1   2021-01-03  True
3   2021-01-04  True
4   2021-01-05  True
3   2021-01-06  False
1   2021-01-05  False
```

Comment: `df['new'] = df['new']==1`.

Comment: @QuangHoang doing this would only create a column with the value 1